# Thunderbird add-on for automatically inserting custom salutation

Tags: thunderbird

I want Thunderbird to automatically insert a salutation when writing an email.

It should take the salutation from the recipient’s address book entry. I know that TB doesn’t offer a suitable field, so an add-on should either create one (if that is possible at all) or use one of the custom fields.

I would prefer entering the full salutation (including `,` or `!`) myself, instead of the add-on trying to build it from multiple fields.

Answer (score 0):

The [**Quicktext**](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/quicktext/) addon is great for inserting custom texts and snippets.

I am using Quicktext for years, and it works well for me. In my case I take the salution from the email (= email sender's name). But I am not sure if it can access the address book. Here is a list of possible variables: http://extensions.hesslow.se/text/3/All+Tags

Comment: Hi Bobby231, thanks for your answer. Could you provide more details, please? See [what makes a high-quality answer](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/387/60). For example, could you describe how a workflow with Quicktext could look like, and if a custom field can be used etc.?

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting downvotes just because some details are missing? I am using Quicktext for years, and it works well for me. In my case I take the salution from the email (= email sender's name). But I am not sure if it can access the address book. Here is a list of possible variables: http://extensions.hesslow.se/text/3/All+Tags/ (I added this to the post as well).